# Querying array of objects in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, ionic2

I have an array of JSON objects

```
array = [{name: "will", age: "18"}
         {name: "Elliott", age: "21"}
        ]
```

Is there a way to get the "age" for any given "name" (as you would do with a SQL statement when querying a database?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
let array = [
  { name: "will", age: "18"}, 
  { name: "john", age: "18"}, 
  { name: "elliott", age: "21"}
]

array.filter((e) => { return e.name === 'john' })
```

Result

```
[ { name: 'john', age: '18' } ]
```

Comment: To extend this, is there a way of editing the "name" and "age" of those indexes in the array without removing the entire object and adding a new one?

Comment: As far as I know you can't in Typescript easily. You must use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extending your object [type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
let queryName = 'will';
array.forEach((obj) => {
    if (obj.name === queryName) {
        console.log(obj.name, obj.age); // will 18
    }
});
```